# how to use subprocess.popen to execute multiple programs which are stored in a list

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

i wanted to ask how can i use subprocess.popen to execute multiple programs simultaneously in python if the names of the program to be executed are stored in a list.I just cant think of how can we do it

Comment: What programs? Do the programs need to be executed with arguments? And what have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: normal python programs without any arguments.I tried using a for loop but it is executing it sequentially

Comment: You can use `multithreading` to create threads, then start the subprocesses in each thread. Why run python programs using `popen` though? Why not just import them and use them like any other code?

Comment: i actually wanted to try to spawn multiple docker container simultaneously using it.@Carcigenicate can you please explain what do you mean by using multithreading through a code if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to give a specific answer since it isn't clear what exactly you're wanting to run (and I don't have much experience with docker). Here's an example though of starting several `ping`s at the same time, which should illustrate how it can be done:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

programs = ["ping 192.168.50.111", "ping 192.168.50.102"]

def run_program(prog_string):
    return Popen(prog_string.split())

# A bit of an abuse of ThreadPool, but it makes cleaning up the threads easier.
with ThreadPool(len(programs)) as pool:
    popens = pool.map(run_program, programs)
```

On my network, this prints:

```
Pinging 192.168.50.111 with 32 bytes of data:
Pinging 192.168.50.102 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.50.102: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.111: bytes=32 time=342ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.102: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.111: bytes=32 time=991ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.111: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.102: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.102: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Ping statistics for 192.168.50.102:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 21ms, Average = 7ms
Reply from 192.168.50.111: bytes=32 time=812ms TTL=64
Ping statistics for 192.168.50.111:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 5ms, Maximum = 991ms, Average = 537ms
```

As you can see, both were started at roughly the same time, and are running at the same time.

`ThreadPool` creates a pool of threads, and runs `run_program` inside the threads. The "program strings" `programs` are passed individually to that function, then the resulting `Popen` is returned, and they're all collectively placed into `popens`.

Unless you really need `Popen` though, you may find that [`run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is easier to use.